# "ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment" when using logical and

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Am writing one condition but unfortuantely getting ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment , am not sure what am i doing wrong here.. Can somebody help me

```
      if((!isEmpty($rootScope.appState.template.contentSelections.upload.JSON))) && (( $rootScope.appState.template.contentSelections.Options.DELIVERY_METHOD == 'email' && $scope.generated.deliveryChannels = "EE/ER")|| ($rootScope.appState.template.contentSelections.Options.DELIVERY_METHOD == 'email_print' && $scope.generated.deliveryChannels = "EE/ER/Print")))
```

I dont see any wrong doing here.. but still getting this error

Comment: At the end `... && $scope.generated.deliveryChannels = "EE/ER/Print")))`

Comment: ohh my bad.. thanks much

Comment: Twice…………………………

Answer (score 1):

```
  if((!isEmpty($rootScope.appState.template.contentSelections.upload.JSON))) && (( $rootScope.appState.template.contentSelections.Options.DELIVERY_METHOD == 'email' && $scope.generated.deliveryChannels == "EE/ER")|| ($rootScope.appState.template.contentSelections.Options.DELIVERY_METHOD == 'email_print' && $scope.generated.deliveryChannels == "EE/ER/Print")))
```

You missed an `=` at the end and in the middle